# What are those devices (BE3AE 002)?

Tags: integrated-circuit

Does anyone know what those devices are? The markings are `BE3AE 002`. I'm assuming they are some kind of temperature sensor.

[image]

Comment: Q is the refdes for a transistor; what is the intended/claimed functionality of the product in which you found these parts?

Comment: On the other side of the PCB, there is a heating pad which heats to approx. 50°C. I was assuming that those were temperature sensors but they could indeed be some kind of transistor as well.

Comment: Is it plausible that R6 could be a thermistor? It's a bit hard to tell, but it looks like it's not clearly connected to the transistors as a pulldown/pullup/biasing network, and simply has direct connections downward.

Comment: Yes that's possible

Comment: They could be transistors because the Q designator. But if you know they are temperature sensors, that might be also true. Transistors can be used as temperature sensors.